How to configure Windows 11 to lock PIN login after 3 failed attempts and enforce password entry using Intune?
I manage a fully cloud-based environment with Intune and Azure AD. I need to enforce the following on Windows 11 devices:

Disable PIN login after 3 failed attempts.
Require the user to use their password for authentication.

I've checked Intune's settings catalog and my local GPO but can't find a direct option. Is there a way to implement this via Intune (built-in, OMA-URI, or script)? Any alternative approaches for a cloud-only setup?
